# SKCameraNode not centered

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skcameranode

I'm working with Swift 3, Xcode and SpriteKit

I have a SKCameraNode named cam, and I put a node at the camera's position to check it:

```
var cam: SKCameraNode!
let cameraNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "hx")

override func didMove(to view: SKView)
{           
    cam = SKCameraNode()
    camera = cam
    addChild(cam)
    cam.position = CGPoint(x: playableRect.midWidth, y: playableRect.midHeight)


    addChild(cameraNode)
}
```

And here's what I got :

The red line is the limit of my playableRect.
The white hexagon is the position of the camera. We can clearly see that the camera right in the center of my playableRect as I wanted, but normally this camera should be in the center of the screen, why is it on the left ?
I mean, normally my cameraNode should always be at the center of the screen, it seems logic.

[image: screenshot]

Can you help me ?

Comment: What is your scene anchor point at?  This usually has issues when it comes to SKCameraNode, I like setting it to .5 .5

Comment: Well, thanks it worked, I didn't even know you could set a scene anchor point. One question that moderators can delete after, how can I mark this thread as solve without any answer ?

Comment: There, made an answer for you LOL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the scene anchor point to (0.5,0.5)